# Does json.dumps call a class dunder method?

Tags: python, json

When attempting to serialize a class to JSON in python you could try to call `json.dumps(my_class_instance)`. However, this will raise `TypeError: Object of type MyClass is not JSON serializable`. There are many different suggestions on how to get around this (i.e. `json.dumps(instance.__dict__)`, `json.dumps(instance, default=...)`, etc.). However, often times you cannot control the call to `dumps()` (i.e. in a web server application that automatically serializes objects to JSON as part of the request/response flow). Is there a way to implement a dunder method or similar on `MyClass` such that a call to `json.dumps(my_class_instance)` will succeed? Implementing `__dict__` does not suffice.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for the `json` module? Specifically, for [the encoder class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)?

Comment: If your framework doesn't allow you to control the call to `json.dumps` explicitly, it should provide its own way to ensure an instance can be encoded. (For example, the  Flask-JSON extension for Flask apps.)

Comment: IIRC the `json.JSONEncoder` class is to extend the functionality of `json.dumps`, which I don't have access to. @chepner thanks for the pointer, I am using FastAPI and it appears they have something similar - https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/. Still, some native way to extend this functionality to classes would be useful imo.